# After submitting the Booking form, there's nothing in the database

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to get this form to work. I created the model, forms.py, views, and linking in the URL files. The form was submitted and I got the 200 status code, so it seems like the POST method went through, but when I logged into the admin panel, there was nothing under the Booking model.

[This is what the lesson_details.html looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAkjL.png)

[This is what it looks like with the booking modal open.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kveiM.png)

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField

STATUS = ((0, "Draft"), (1, "Published"))


class Coach(models.Model):
    RECREATIONAL = 'recreational'
    FREESTYLE = 'freestyle'
    DANCE = 'dance'
    PAIRS = 'pairs'

    SPECIALIZATION_CHOICES = [
        (RECREATIONAL, 'Recreational'),
        (FREESTYLE, 'Freestyle'),
        (DANCE, 'Dance'),
        (PAIRS, 'Pairs'),
    ]

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a brief bio")
    image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder', help_text="Image must be a square")
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=SPECIALIZATION_CHOICES, default=RECREATIONAL)
    years_of_experience = models.PositiveIntegerField(default='1', help_text="Enter a positive integer.")
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pk']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Coach {self.first_name} {self.last_name}'


class Lesson(models.Model):
    # code from https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/27/moving-to-django-3-field-choices-enumeration-types/
    BEGINNER = 'beginner'
    INTERMEDIATE = 'intermediate'
    ADVANCED = 'advanced'

    LEVEL_CHOICES = [
        (BEGINNER, 'Beginner'),
        (INTERMEDIATE, 'Intermediate'),
        (ADVANCED, 'Advanced'),
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    lesson_start = models.DateTimeField(help_text="Date: YYYY-MM-DD Time: HH:MM:SS")
    lesson_level = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=LEVEL_CHOICES, default=BEGINNER)
    duration = models.DurationField(help_text="Format HH:MM:SS")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coach = models.ForeignKey(Coach, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lesson_coach')
    content = models.TextField()
    featured_image = CloudinaryField('image', default='placeholder')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='lesson_likes', blank=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['lesson_start']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def number_of_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()


class Feedback(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='feedbacks')
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_feedbacks')
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Feedback {self.body} by {self.username}'


class Booking(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey(Lesson, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lesson_bookings')
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_bookings')
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    contact_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact_message = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Contact message submitted by {self.name} on {self.created_on}'
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from django.views import generic, View
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Lesson, Coach, Feedback, Contact, Booking
from .forms import FeedbackForm, ContactForm, BookingForm


class LessonList(generic.ListView):
    model = Lesson
    queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('lesson_start')
    template_name = 'index.html'
    paginate_by = 6


class About(generic.ListView):
    model = Coach
    queryset = Coach.objects.filter(status=1).order_by('first_name')
    template_name = 'about.html'
    paginate_by = 6


class Contact(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact_success')


class LessonDetail(View):

    def get(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(status=1)
        lesson = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        coach = lesson.coach
        feedbacks = lesson.feedbacks.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
        liked = False
        if lesson.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        booking_form = BookingForm() 

        return render(
            request,
            "lesson_detail.html",
            {
                "lesson": lesson,
                "feedbacks": feedbacks,
                "coach": coach,
                "submitted_feedback": False,
                "liked": liked,
                "feedback_form": FeedbackForm(),
                "booking_form": booking_form,
            },
        )

    def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Lesson.objects.filter(status=1)
        lesson = get_object_or_404(queryset, slug=slug)
        coach = lesson.coach
        feedbacks = lesson.feedbacks.filter(approved=True).order_by('-created_on')
        liked = False
        if lesson.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True

        feedback_form = FeedbackForm(data=request.POST)
        booking_form = BookingForm(data=request.POST)

        if feedback_form.is_valid():
            feedback_form.instance.email = request.user.email
            feedback_form.instance.name = request.user.username
            feedback_form.instance.username_id = request.user.id
            feedback = feedback_form.save(commit=False)
            feedback.lesson = lesson
            feedback.save()
        else:
            feedback_form = FeedbackForm()

        if booking_form.is_valid():
            booking = booking_form.save(commit=False)
            booking.lesson = lesson
            booking.user_id = request.user.id
            booking.save()

        return render(
            request,
            "lesson_detail.html",
            {
                "lesson": lesson,
                "feedbacks": feedbacks,
                "coach": coach,
                "submitted_feedback": True,
                "feedback_form": FeedbackForm(),
                "booking_form": booking_form,
                "liked": liked
            },
        )
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Feedback, Contact, Booking


class FeedbackForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Feedback
        fields = ('body',)


class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'contact_message')


class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('lesson', 'username', 'email', 'phone', 'message',)
```

URLs.py

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.LessonList.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('about/', views.About.as_view(), name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.Contact.as_view(), name='contact'),
    path('contact/success/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='contact_success.html'), name='contact_success'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.LessonDetail.as_view(), name='lesson_detail'),
    path('like/<slug:slug>/', login_required(views.LessonLike.as_view()), name='lesson_like'),
]
```

lesson_details.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="masthead">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row g-3">
            <div class="d-block col-lg-8 masthead-image img-fluid">
                <!-- to display placeholder image if feautre image was not uploaded -->
                {% if "placeholder" in lesson.featured_image.url %}
                <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dukqu7lia/image/upload/v1696354385/placeholder.jpg" width="100%"
                    height="100%">
                {% else %}
                <img src=" {{ lesson.featured_image.url }} " width="100%">
                {% endif %}
            </div>
            <div class="d-lg-block col-lg-4 masthead-coach">
                <div class="coach-image d-sm-none d-lg-block m-auto">
                    {% if "placeholder" in coach.image.url %}
                    <!-- to display placeholder image if feautre image was not uploaded -->
                    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dukqu7lia/image/upload/v1697297007/coach_placeholder.png"
                        class="img" width="100%">
                    {% else %}
                    <img class="img-fluid coach-image" src=" {{ coach.image.url }} " width="100%">
                    {% endif %}</div>
                <div class="d-lg-block coach-text m-3">
                    <h4 class="coach-name">Coach {{ coach.first_name }}</h4>
                    <p class="specialization">{{ coach.specialization|capfirst }}</p>
                </div>
                <!-- only logged in user can press the button -->
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <div class="booking-button-container m-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg booking-button rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#bookingModal">Book this lesson!</button>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="booking-button-container">
                    <button class="btn btn-lg booking-button rounded-pill" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#bookingModal">Book this lesson!</button>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Booking Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="bookingModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bookingModalLabel" aria-hidden="True">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content p-3">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="bookingModalLabel" id="bookingModalLabel">Request a Booking</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          </button>
        </div>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="lesson_name" class="col-form-label">Lesson:</label>
              <input type="text" name="lesson" class="form-control" value="{{ lesson.title }}" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-form-label">Username*</label>
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ user.username }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email*</label>
              <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" value="{{ user.email }}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="phone" class="col-form-label">Phone*</label>
              <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="012-345-6789" pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="message" class="col-form-label">Message*</label>
              <textarea name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Leave your message here!" required></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer mt-3">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg booking-button rounded-pill px-5">Book!</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="modal-body">
            <h5>You must log in to your account to make a booking!</h5>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 lesson-text">
            <!-- display lesson's level -->
            {% if lesson.lesson_level == 'beginner'%}
            <div class="lesson-banner banner-bkgd-beginner">
                <p class="difficulty">beginner</p>
            </div>
            {% elif lesson.lesson_level == 'intermediate'%}
            <div class="lesson-banner banner-bkgd-intermediate">
                <p class="difficulty">intermediate</p>
            </div>
            {% elif lesson.lesson_level == 'advanced'%}
            <div class="lesson-banner banner-bkgd-advanced">
                <p class="difficulty">advanced</p>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
            <h2 class="lesson-title p-2 mt-2">{{ lesson.title }}</h2>
            <p class="lesson-time-label">Start time: <span class="lesson-time">{{ lesson.lesson_start }}</span></p>
            <p class="lesson-duration-label">Duration: <span class="lesson-duration">{{ lesson.duration }}</span></p>
            <p class="lesson-location-label">Location: <span class="lesson-location">{{ lesson.location }}</span></p>

            <!-- safe filter is used to make sure the conten is being displayed -->
            <span class="card-text lesson-description">{{ lesson.content | safe }}</span>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col card mb-4 mt-3 left top">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <!-- Likes -->
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <strong>
                            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                            <form class="d-inline" action="{% url 'lesson_like' lesson.slug %}" method="POST">
                                {% csrf_token %}
                                {% if liked %}
                                <button type="submit" name="lesson_id" value="{{lesson.slug}}" class="btn-like"><i
                                        class="fas fa-heart"></i></button>
                                {% else %}
                                <button type="submit" name="lesson_id" value="{{lesson.slug}}" class="btn-like"><i
                                        class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
                                {% endif %}
                            </form>
                            {% else %}
                            <span class="text-secondary"><i class="far fa-heart"></i></span>
                            {% endif %}
                            <!-- The number of likes goes before the closing strong tag -->
                            <span class="text-secondary">{{ lesson.number_of_likes }}</span>
                        </strong>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Number of feedbacks -->
                    <div class="col-1">
                        {% with feedbacks.count as total_feedbacks %}
                        <strong class="text-secondary"><i class="far fa-comments"></i>
                            {{ total_feedbacks }}
                        </strong>
                        {% endwith %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- horizontal line -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Feedbacks area -->
        <div class="col-md-8 card mb-4 mt-3">
            <h3>Feedbacks:</h3>
            <div class="card-body">
                {% for feedback in feedbacks %}
                <div class="feedbacks" style="padding: 10px;">
                    <p class="font-weight-bold">
                        {{ feedback.username }}
                        <span class="feedback-time font-weight-normal">
                            {{ feedback.created_on }}
                        </span> wrote:
                    </p>
                    {{ feedback.body | linebreaks }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Feedback form -->
        <div class="col-md-4 card mb-4  mt-3 ">
            <div class="card-body">
                {% if submitted_feedback %}
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    Your feedback is waiting approval
                </div>
                {% else %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <h3>Leave a feedback:</h3>
                <p>Posting as: {{ user.username }}</p>
                <form method="post" class="feedback-form">
                    {{ feedback_form | crispy }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-form my-3 p-3 rounded-pill">Submit</button>
                </form>
                {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: If the booking form has errors, the html page just displays a fresh form without actually showing the errors.  So I imagine the problem is that the form **wasn't** saved, because it had errors.  But your html page doesn't actually **show** any errors, so you never even knew there **were** any.

Comment: @JohnGordon is there any way you would suggest to have it show the error so I would know what's wrong with it?

Comment: In general, you would add `{{form.FIELD.errors}}` next to each field, where `FIELD` is the actual name of a field, i.e. `{{form.email.errors}}`.  There is also `{{form.non_field_errors}}` for errors that are not specific to one field.

Comment: By the way, this is the downside of writing your own custom form display in the html page.  You don't get all the extra display items that come with the standard `{{form.as_p}}` display -- you have to remember to do them yourself.

Comment: @JohnGordon I wanted to write my own custom form just because I wanted certain fields to be filled automatically when the user logged in. Maybe `{{ form.as_p ))` can do it too but I haven't look into that yet